# Explanation of generic <T extends Comparable<? super T>> in collection.sort/ comparable code?

Tags: java, generics

I use comparable interface all the time to provided natural ordering for my class through collection.sort.

Basically if I have a person class, I will get it to implement Comparable interface and will provide the implementation of compareTo. However in the definition of Collections.sort in javadocs, I see this signature

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

I don't understand this generics definition at all? Shouldn't it just say

```
<T implements Comparable<T>>
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: It means that either the class `T` itself or one of its super classes implements `Comparable`.

Comment: @PM77-1 Thank you for this simplistic explanation and it appears that `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` is the most correct

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Actually, it means that T *can* implement `Comparable<? super T>`, not just `Comparable<T>`.

For example, it means that a `Student` class can implement `Comparable<Person>`, where `Student` is a subclass of `Person`:

```
public class Person {}

public class Student extends Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    @Override public int compareTo(Person that) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In this case, a List can be sorted by `Collections.sort()` but only based on `Person`'s properties, because you pass the `Student` instance into `compareTo()` as a `Person` (unless you downcast it, of course).

In practice however, you'll never see a `Student` class implement `Comparable<Person>`. That's because `Person` will probably have implemented `Comparable<Person>`, and `Student` inherits it implementation. The end result is the same however: you can pass a `List<Student>` to `Collections.sort()` and have it sorted on `Person`'s properties.

The difference between `Comparable<T>` and `Comparable<? super T>` is more obvious in [the overloaded version of Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) that takes a `Comparator<? super T>`:

```
class ByAgeAscending implements Comparator<Person> {
    @Override public int compare(Person a, Person b) {
        return a.getAge() < b.getAge();
    }
}

List<Student> students = getSomeStudents();
Collections.sort(students, new ByAgeAscending());
```

Answer (score 6):

You always use *extends* with generics wildcards, even if the type parameter implements an interface.

If you look at a class that implements [*Comparable*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), you'll see that it actually (should) implement `Comparable<T>`, where T is the class itself.

It makes sense if you think about the type paramter passed to the [*Comparable*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and how it's used in the [*compareTo()*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method.

As PM 77-1 has eloquently pointed out, the *super* keyword allows for either the class, T, or one of its parents to implement [*Comparable*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).