# Why is this generic method to find the largest in a Java array not compiling?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm trying to learn generics in Java, and I would've thought this method would work for finding the largest in an array:

```
  public static <T> T largestInArray(T[] inputArray){
    T largest = inputArray[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < inputArray.length - 1; i++){
      if (inputArray[i] > largest)
        largest = inputArray[i];
    }
    return largest;
  }
```

but I get an error saying: bad operand types for binary operator '>' How should I do this?

Comment: The `>` operand can only be use for numbers (`int`, `double`, `long`, etc.). The wrapper classes for those types will be unboxed so those will work, but others won't.

Comment: The `>` in Java does not work with Object (generics). You need to use `Comparator<T>` or `Comparable<T>` to compare objects in the array.

Comment: For future questions, if something does not compile, please always give us the full error (stack trace) including the exact line number where the compiler complaints about your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only use comparison operators on numeric types. If you want to compare generic types, you'll have to ensure they implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), and call `Comparable.compare()`:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T largestInArray(T[] inputArray) {
    //...
    if (inputArray[i].compareTo(largest) > 0) {
    //...
}
```

`compareTo()` will return 0 for equal values, < 0 if the target object has precedence, and > 0 if the argument has precedence.

Alternatively, you can use a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) instead of relying on the natural order:

```
public static <T> T largestInArray(T[] inputArray, Comparator<? super T> comparator) {
    //...
    if (comparator.compare(inputArray[i], largest) > 0) {
    //...
}
```

`compare()` works similar to `compareTo()` above.

Note that these are both already implemented as `Collections` helpers, which you can easily call by wrapping the array:

```
Collections.max(Arrays.asList(inputArray)/*, comparator*/)
```

Comment: Maybe you should include something about how Java generics require you to state requirements up-front, unlike e.g. C++ templates that work on any type as long as the code of the template can compile against it.

Comment: now is it OK that I put into the header: <T extends Comparable> instead of <T extends Comparable<? super T>>?

Comment: @Derry No, `Comparable` is a [raw type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/1553851) and should be avoided. At minimum, you need `<T extends Comparable<T>>`. But the version in my answer will give [the most flexibility to the caller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25779184/1553851).

Comment: it did compile, but in that case, what would be a case that my code wouldn't?

Comment: @Derry I didn't say it wouldn't compile, just that it should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Since Java defines comparison operators `>`, `<`, `>=`, and `<=` only for numeric types, you cannot apply them to objects, including generic ones.

Instead, you need to tell the compiler that objects of `T` will implement [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. You wouldn't be able to use `>`, but you would be able to do what you need by calling `compareTo`:

```
if (inputArray[i].compareTo(largest) > 0) // Replaces inputArray[i] > largest
```