# How to avoid unchecked casts in a Java Generics extended Comparable interface?

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-conversion, type-erasure

Why is the unsafe cast `(T)` needed in this generic interface? If `T` is comparable to itself, i.e. implements `ExtendedComparable<super of T>` which means also `ExtendedComparable<T>`, then why does type erasure require `ExtendedComparable<T>` to be cast to T?

```
/* @param <T> T must be comparable to itself or any of its superclass
 * (comparables are consumers, thus acc. to the PECS principle 
 * = producer-extends,consumer-super we use the bounded wildcard type "super")
 */   
public interface ExtendedComparable<T extends ExtendedComparable<? super T>> {
    Comparator<? super T> getComparator();
    default boolean greaterThen(T toCompare) {
        return getComparator().compare((T) this, toCompare) > 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This post can be of your help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25783345/4867374

Answer (score 5):

Because there is no guarantee that `this` is actually an instance of class `T` or even extend it.

For example consider this:

```
public class T0 implements ExtendComparable<T0> {...}
public class T1 implements ExtendComparable<T0> {...}
```

In `T0` complies fine as it complies with the bound: `T0 extends ExtendComparable<T0>` and T0 is super of T0. In this case `this` is an instance of `T0` here so you are fine; the cast `(T)this` (thus `(T0)this`) makes sense.

With `T1` the declaration is correct also because the bound is applied to `T0` no `T1`, `T` is substituted `T0`. However `this` is `T1` and `T1` is not super nor a child of `T0`. Yes, both implement 
`ExtendedCompatible<T0>`, but you cannot cast between siblings. For example Integer and Double extend Number but `(Integer) new Double(0.0)` fails. 
So too does the cast `(T)` translated to `(T0)` fail.

The assumption you are making is that `T` is going to be set to the same as the class that is been declared and currently there is no way to force those semantics. I hope this will change at some point in future releases of the Java language but perhaps there is actual reason why the Java language "task force" are avoiding to do so.

There is a way to avoid the cast altogether but is better when you make `ExtendedCompatible` an abstract class rather than an interface.

You can declare a final field of type `T` which value would be set by a protected constructor by extending class which in turn must pass `this` as its value:

```
public abstract class ExtendedCompatible<T extends ExtendedCompatible<? super T>> {
  private final T thiz;

  protected ExtendedCompatible(final T thiz) {
     if (this != thiz) throw new IllegalArgumentException("you must pass yourself");
     this.thiz = thiz;
  }
  ...

  public class MyExtendedCompatible extends ExtendedCompatible<MyExtendedCompatible> {
     public MyExtendedCompatible() {
           super(this);
     }
  }
```

The price you pay is the extra memory consumption of having a silly reference to itself and the added code/CPU burden of passing `this` to the parent constructor.

Another would be to declare an abstract method to get the `T` (this):

```
// Parent abstract class:
   protected abstract T getThiz();
// Child class... for each class:
   protected MyChildClass getThiz() { return this; }
```

Comment: that'a s very detailed and good answer IMO. stack overflow has a reputation of awarding only top rated users sometimes, but this is a really good one. +1

Comment: Thanks. That is right. We intended the interface to be used for many enums. But, unfortunately, the proposed work around is not suitable for enums, because they do not support inheritace and thus could not be derived from an abstract class. The 2nd work around is also not quite feasible, as each method in the interface would need to check getThiz() != this (in Java 9, at least all these identical checks could be refactored into a private interface method) and each enum would need to implement getThiz().

Comment: @ms34449 What about enums? I think you can override methods per constant in you include a body in their declaration. EDIT ah! you mean across enums not across constants.