# Java Generics - Can not cast K to Long

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

I have below code which compiles perfectly fine with maven but Intellij keeps on giving me error saying `Inconvertible types can not cast 'K' to java.lang.Long`.

```
public class BPlusTree<K extends Comparable<K>, T> {

    public void debug(K time) {
      Long l = (Long) time;
    }
}
```

When I remove the `extends Comparable<K>` part from the class definition, intellij stops giving this error. What is happening here? I know this casting can throw a runtime `ClassCastException` but why the compilation error?

Comment: What did you actually mean when you wrote `K extends Comparable<K>`?

Comment: Probably not a compilation error. IntelliJ is probably just letting you know that your code is broken. Why the error goes away when you remove the constraint, I don't know.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I want to make sure that my 'K' is comparable (it provides compareTo method)?

Comment: So what happens when `time` is a `String`?

Comment: @Nullpointer The fact that K extends Comparable says nothing about whether or not it necessarily can be cast to a long. "Broken" might not have been the right word. "Just asking for a runtime exception" would be better.

Comment: @Nullpointer So then the question becomes: what is `K` going to be in your code, concretely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Comparable` is a bit weird when dealing with generics.  I believe the correct definition is below:

```
class BPlusTree<K extends Comparable<? super K>, T> {

    public void debug(K time) {
      Long l = (Long) time;
    }

}
```

There's a good explanation of why it needs to be this way here: [Explanation of generic <T extends Comparable<? super T>> in collection.sort/ comparable code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779184/explanation-of-generic-t-extends-comparable-super-t-in-collection-sort-com)