# Bounded type paratemers in Collections.max()

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I am tryng to understand how generics works in Java. The following code is from `Collections.max()` method of OpenJDK.

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll) {
    Iterator<? extends T> i = coll.iterator();
    T candidate = i.next();

    while (i.hasNext()) {
        T next = i.next();
        if (next.compareTo(candidate) > 0)
            candidate = next;
    }
    return candidate;
}
```

- `<T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>`

  - The method expects `T` to be a subclass of `Object` and it should implement `Comparable` interface in order to compare the elements of the collection.
  - (a) a collection always stores typed objects, which are anyways sub-types of `Object`. Is `T extends Object` redundant in this case ?
  - (b) `Comparable<T>` is not enough ? why do we need `Comparable<? super T>` ?
- `max(Collection<? extends T> coll)`

  - (c) Again my doubt here is that, why is `Collection<? extends T>` needed ? Can it be `Collection<T>` ?

Comment: @Clyky, the part about `<T extends Object & ...>` is a duplicate of the question you linked and https://stackoverflow.com/a/19488411/814206 gives a good answer.  That leaves the part "why do we need `Comparable<? super T>` and `Collection<? extends T>`", perhaps OP can edit the question.  There might exist a duplicate for the latter part as well.

Comment: The "Why do we need `<Comparable <? super T>`" part is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/25779184/814206.