# Generics and Wild Card

Tags: java, generics

I am designing an implementation of a BinarySearchTree, although I am stuck with an issue that I have not encountered before. I also have little understanding of how to fix this:

```
The type K is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <K extends Comparable<? super K>> of the type BST<K,V>
```

This is the error I get after creating an abstract class named `BST<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>` and then having another class that extends this named `RectangleBST<K,V>` . So `RectangleBST<K,V> extends BST<K,V>` but I get the error when I use `BST<K, V>`.

One solution was to use extends `BST<Integer, Rectangle>`, although would that mean that I have now inherited the methods specifically for a Key of Integer type and a Value of Rectangle type?

Another may be to have the comparable in the RectangleBST instead, although I believe that my plan is to compare keys in BST rather than RectangleBST?

Comment: Make it `RectangleBST<K extends Comparable<? super K>,V> extends BST<K,V>`. But I am not sure why you declare `K extends Comparable<? super K>` instead of `K extends Comparable<K>`.

Comment: @tsolakp https://stackoverflow.com/q/25779184/1553851

Comment: @shmosel. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @tsolakp That did indeed fix it. Could you explain why and what exactly was wrong with the way I was initially trying to implement it? (If it's too much trouble)

Thanks!

Comment: @Andreas gave a good explanation. Personally I think Java compiler should be able to infer type of `K` in `extends` definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic type parameters don't have to be named the same, so to better see the difference, let's rename them:

```
BST<A extends Comparable<? super A>, B>
```

```
RectangleBST<C, D> extends BST<C, D>
```

That works similar to a function call:

```
bst(int a, int b)
```

```
rectangleBst(int c, int d) {
    bst(c, d);
}
```

However, it only works if `c` is compatible with `a`. I mean, if `C` is compatible with `A`.

It is not, since `C` can be any type, even a type that doesn't implement/extend `Comparable`. Since `A` requires the type parameter to implement/extend `Comparable`, `C` is not compatible.

To make it compatible, you also need to restrict `C` to types that implement/extend `Comparable`:

```
RectangleBST<C extends Comparable<? super C>, D> extends BST<C, D>
```

Now `C` is compatible with `A`.

---

Ok, now use the names you want:

```
BST<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>
```

```
RectangleBST<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> extends BST<K, V>
```

Just remember, that the `K` in `RectangleBST` is not the *same* `K` as the `K` in `BST`. It is a different `K` that is mapped to the `K` in `BST`, same as `C` was mapped to `A`.

Comment: I think I got it!

Is there then a difference between

````
RectangleBST<C extends Comparable<? super C>, D> extends BST<C, D>
````

and

````
RectangleBST<C, D> extends BST<C extends Comparable<? super C>, D>
````

Or is the first time that the Generic C is responsible for declaring its type restrictions for any other extended class and/or implemented Interfaces?

Comment: @dan The second is not valid syntax. Same as you can't write `rectangleBst(c, d) { bst(int c, int d); }`. The type/restriction must be defined where the parameter is *declared*, not where it is used.