# Comparable interface implementation

Tags: java

`Comparable` is an interface which contains the method `compareTo()`.

In the code that  uses a generic method to return the largest of three comparable objects, `compareTo()` method is used directly without implementation. How is that possible? Is it because we are"extending" that interface in the class and not "implementing" it?

```
public class Max {

    public static <T extends Comparable <T>> T maximum(T x, T y, T z) {
        T max=x;

        if (y.compareTo(max) > 0)
            max=y;

        if (z.compareTo(max) > 0)
            max=z;

        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because it's implemented in whatever `T` is when `Max::maximum` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Since you declare `T extends Comparable<T>` any object passed with the type `T` must implement the `Comparable` interface.

`T` can be any object of your choosing as long as it has `YourType implement Comparable<YourType>`. So whatever you pass to your `maximum` method has implemented `compareTo`.

Edit: 
Oh and the syntax is admittedly a bit confusing with generics. If you add `extends SomeInterface` to your generic type, it expects an `implements` and not an `extends`.

Comment: But I suppose "extends" can be used in general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces).

Comment: @Mithra yeah that's what it means in this case. I just wanted to point out the possibly confusing syntax in case that was the reason of confusion.

Comment: @Mithra Note that for maximum flexibility you should be using `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779184/)).