# What does <T extends Comparable<T>> mean?

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I was looking over the TheAlgorithms repository for java and came to this first: https://github.com/TheAlgorithms/Java/blob/master/Searches/SearchAlgorithm.java. I see `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, and I don't know what this means. I only know a little bit about generics and I know that the syntax has something to with parameter type bounds, but it would be great if someone could clarify how this has to do with `Comparable<T>`, and what `Comparable<T>` is.

There are some other questions on this forum similar to mine dealing with implementing `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, but the answers haven't really clarified what `Comparable<T>` is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you have the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface which roughly looks like:

```java
public interface Comparable<T> {

    int compareTo(T other);
}
```

As you can see, the type parameter of `Comparable` is used as the parameter of the `compareTo` method. Typically, the type argument for `T` is the same class which is implementing the `Comparable` interface. This generic setup facilitates comparing instances of the same type with each other. Here's an example:

```java
public class Name implements Comparable<Name> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Name other) {
        // compute & return result
    }
}
```

Now let's say you have a method which should return the maximum of two objects according to their natural order. Such a method could look like the following:

```java
public static <U extends Comparable<U>> U max(U left, U right) {
    return left.compareTo(right) >= 0 ? left : right;
}
```

***Note:** Used `U` as the type variable instead of `T` to show it is separate from the `T` used in the `Comparable` interface.*

The above is a generic method. The type variable `U` is upper-bounded by `Comparable<U>`. What this means is that the type argument used in place of `U` must be assignable to (i.e. subtype of) `Comparable<U>`. For instance, if we use `Name` as the type argument it will work because `Name` is assignable to `Comparable<Name>`. The reason for specifying the upper-bound as `Comparable<U>` is that the method needs to call `compareTo` in order to function properly.

```java
Name name1 = ...;
Name name2 = ...;

Name max = max(name1, name2); // U is inferred to be Name
```

As shown above, having `U` as the return type also allows assigning the result to a variable of the same type as the arguments.

---

Note that for maximum flexibility the `max` method should actually be declared like so:

```java
public static <U extends Comparable<? super U>> U max(U left, U right) {
    return left.compareTo(right) >= 0 ? left : right;
}
```

The difference being the use of `Comparable<? super U>` as the upper-bound instead of `Comparable<U>`. These two Q&As should help explain why using `? super U` offers greater flexibility:

- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/)
- [Explanation of generic `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` in collection.sort/ comparable code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779184/)

Comment: Why isn't `U max(U left, U right)` in the curly brackets of the method, in your example?

Comment: That `U` is the return type of the method. The type variable `U` is, however, declared in angle brackets which is what allows using `U` as the return type: `<U extends Comparable<U>> U max(U left, U right)`. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, we can decompose this puzzling-looking expression into its elements and put them back together.

### Premise

We have a method `find(? array[], ? key)` that looks for a `key` within an array. We want to use this method for different types of input arguments, e.g., an array/key of `String`, `Integer`, whatever.

### Parametric Type `<U>`

We put `<U>` in front of the method signature to indicate that it is a *parametric method*. This means that in the rest of the declaration, `U` is a placeholder that will be replaced by a type where the method is invoked. *(I use `U` instead of `T` for reasons that will become obvious below.)*

But, we can't replace `U` with *any* type because to be able to correctly implement the method, we want to be able to compare the elements in the array to each other (for instance to sort the array). The common interface used to define this behavior is [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). It has a single method, `compareTo`.

### Type Bound `<U extends Comparable>`

To require that the `U` type parameter only be replaceable (instantiable) with a type that is a subtype of `Comparable`, we impose the *type bound*: `extends Comparable`. This allow us to call `compareTo` on `key` or on array elements such as `array[0]` in a type safe way.

However, we're not done here, because `Comparable` is itself a generic type: `Comparable<T>`, where the type parameter `T` governs the type of the parameter for `compareTo`. We thus need to instantiate `T` when we use `Comparable<T>`.

### Instantiating `Comparable<T>`

Before instantiating `T` in `Comparable`, our expression is `<U extends Comparable<T>>`. We need to replace `T` with the desired type. What should be the type of the parameter to `compareTo`? If we are passing an array of `String` to `find`, we would be comparing `Strings`, etc. In the generic case we are passing an array of `U` to `find`, so we would like to compare objects of type `U`. So in this case we instantiate `T` in `Comparable<T>` with another generic type, `U`: `<U extends Comparable<U>>`, which is the same as `<T extends Comparable<T>>`

Answer (score 0):

> It means that T is a class type which is subtype of or inheriting Comparable which also accepts  a generic type and it should be of same type as the class which is represented by  T here.

E.g.

replace T by Employee class and Employee class definition is as below.

Employee is now T and Comparable's compareTo method must also accept Employee as parameter as T is now Employee  per Comparable.

```
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```